# Discord JS message.member.roles.cache.some

Tags: discord, discord.js

i tried making a command with role restrictions, and i'm having problems with role restriction itself.
`if(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Role1')) return message.reply("You can't use the command!")`

So, if i use only 1 role as restriction it works completey fine, but as long as i add second role

`if(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Role1'||'Role2')) return message.reply("You can't use the command!")`

It turns into a mess, anyone, even a person without any roles can use the command! I tried many ways of making it work, i tried using Role ID's instead of names like this

`message.member.roles.cache.has('role-id-here'||'role2id-here');`
and still, it didn't work!

I would appreciate any help to me with that.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditional is incorrect. It is not set up correctly and I think you may not understand the `OR` operator `||` completely.

```
// your original 
 role.name === 'Role1' || 'Role2'`
```

The or operator `||` is misused in this statement. The `||` returns the left side if that value is `true` and returns the right side if the left value is `false`. The left side of your original condition is `role.name === 'Role1` therefore if this is `false` return `'Role2`'

What you want to do is
`role => (role.name === 'Role1' || role.name === 'Role2')`